# How to center, and display ip in tkinter?

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

Current code: (yes it is fullscreen)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter as tk
import socket

class FullScreenApp(object):
  def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
    self.master=master`enter code here`
    pad=3
    self._geom='200x200+0+0'
    master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
    master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
    master.bind('<Escape>',self.toggle_geom)
  def toggle_geom(self,event):
    geom=self.master.winfo_geometry()
    print(geom,self._geom)
    self.master.geometry(self._geom)
    self._geom=geom

root=tk.Tk()
app=FullScreenApp(root)
root.mainloop()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("gmail.com",80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

---

Thats what i have so far, it prints the ip to the console just stuck on parsing the values to tkinter

Comment: Use the `Label` widget. Additionally, you must put your code before `root.mainloop`, otherwise the code beneath will only run when you close the window.

Comment: Post indented code that can possible run.  I added spaces for you.